# Buttons in Glade, why are they square?

Tags: python, gtk, containers, glade

I'm new at GTK. I'm using Glade to make an interface and just want to insert objects (like buttons and others) into a container. 
I've choosen `GtkFixed` so that all elements can be freely located and sized.
The problem is that when i drag a button for example, the button apparently gets it size from the parent (in this case the container) and takes a square shape.
Here's an image [image: Screen capture]

I want the button to take the standard size, just like a rectangule or something. What i'm i doing wrong? I've checked some options in the container but can't figure out the way.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hexagon buttons in GTK+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957525/hexagon-buttons-in-gtk)

Comment: I'm just dragging and dropping a button in the container and asking why is squared, when it's suppouse to be a rectangule like any other button.

Comment: Select the button, scroll to the bottom of the "Comunes" tab, and you should see something like "Width request" and "Height request" (I don't know if those will be translated) where you can change the size of the button. When you are using GtkFixed or GtkLayout, you are on your own with sizing and positioning everything. Most GTK+ programs don't use either, instead using GtkBox and GtkGrid and letting GTK+ determine what the best sizes should be. That being said, good luck.

Comment: Ok, i'm using GtkBox and seems pretty much easy to use. Should i erase this answer?
Thanks.

Comment: No need to erase anything :) What theme are you using, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the tick from `Height request` and `Width request` (I don't know the equivalent names in your language).

Besides, you should be aware that GtkFixed is difficult to use when the window can be resized. GtkBox is often easier.

[image: Screenshot of Common tab]

Comment: Thanks, but I've disabled Width and Height requests and the button is still squared. Any other idea?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the gtk+/glade version you are using? Or the OS?